# Deleting files older than 7 days, with exception for 1st day of the month

Tags: powershell

I need a scipt, that will delete a files older than 7 days, with exception for 1st day of the month.
Files created at 1st day of the month shouldnt be deleted. The part that i created for files older than 7 days works propperly, but i cant exclude the files from each 1st of month.

I tried to get the work done by following code, but the scipts is still deleting the files from 1st day of the month, even after adding the -notlike statement

```
Get-ChildItem C:\PSScripts\test -Recurse -Directory | 
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) -and $_.CreationTime -notlike (GET-DATE -Format "MM/dd/yyyy" -Day 1) } |
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the same format to CreationTime as you do to Get-Date:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Scripts\Powershell\TestFolder -Recurse -Directory | 
Where-Object {(Get-Date($_.CreationTime) -Format "MM/dd/yyyy") -notlike (GET-DATE -Format "MM/dd/yyyy" -Day 1) }
```

That then returns only those that are not created on the 1st of the month

Comment: Great! Please do mark this as an accepted answer if your issue is resolved :)

Comment: i also found another solution that works i meantime, so im also posting it there for someone who will search for in the future: `Get-ChildItem C:\PSScripts\test -Recurse -Directory |
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) -and $_.LastWriteTime.Day -notlike 1 }|
 Remove-Item -Force -Recurse`

Answer (score 0):

I found also this solution in meantime, it seems to work so I am posting it also for someone who can have the same issue in the future, what I did was the following:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\PSScripts\test -Recurse -Directory |
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) -and $_.LastWriteTime.Day -notlike 1 }|
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```